# Need help aligning/centering navigation bar & table content (CSS)

Tags: html, css

My code:

**HTML**

---

```
<body>

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header">
<!-- Start NavBar -->
    <div id="navbar" name="nav-top">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- End NavBar/Start Content -->

<div id="content">

<div id="inner">

<!-- Content Header -->

  <table id="table_1">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="tab_head">
        <th><h1>About me | Section 1</h1></th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="para_1">
        <td><h3>Hello and Welcome!</h3></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<!-- Content Body -->

<table id="table_2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah BLah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

<div id="my-footer">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "footer"</div>

</div>
<!-- Add JS -->
</body>
```

---

**CSS**

---

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 3em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B9EFF;  }

#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 730px; /* 730px width was 800px before, but changed to slide navbar to right */
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden; }

#navbar li {
    float: left; }

#navbar li a {
    width:150px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #a3a3a3;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

#navbar li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }

a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #2B9EFF;
    color: #141414;
    font-weight:lighter; }

/* Content */

table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#para_1 td {
    text-align:center;
}

#table_2 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    margin
}

#my-footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    clear:both;
    background:#2B9EFF;
    text-align:center; }
```

---

The main concern of mine—if you haven't noticed already—is the fact that my main navigation bar that should be sitting on top of everything else, is not centered on the page. What I've had to put up with so far is a half-well done styling, and that eventually lead to what I have now. It seems like I'm able to adjust it slightly by setting a width in terms of pixels, but when I try to work it with percentages, it blows over.

The second bit I'm trying to get to work is the content below, which contains my abstract of sorts and what will eventually host certain other things (links, images, etc.). I thought I could work it with one table, but I could not for the life of my get the "abstract" (Blah) content to be centered. So, what I did then was create a second table, thinking I could adjust the margins for that table on both sides (right & left) to center said abstract.

**It didn't work.**

I'm currently working with Adobe CS6 and started the page using the liquid grid-layout. I want to focus on a layout/style that will also consider the overall different resolutions/dimensions of user's displays. In other words, I want it to adjust when viewed via mobile or tablet.

Please list **any** advice. I'm a complete novice when it comes to this stuff, so I feel like coming here will give me a better chance to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Feel free to ask for more information, but I think what I've provided so far should be sufficient considering my initial query.

**What can I do to adjust my navigation bar?**
**Can I keep my current elements in the position/style they're in while considering the liquid grid-layout, or do I have to try a different path?**
**Why can't I add to the right side of the margin for the second table when I could for the left side?**

Thank-you for any tips you can come up with!

*Kindest Regards*,

- T.R.G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the HTML the way it was, but I ended up going with this on the CSS:

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    /* float: none; */
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    float:none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B9EFF;  }

#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;/* 730px width was 800px before, but changed to slide navbar to right */
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 20% 0 20%;
    overflow:hidden; }

table {
    width: 100%;
} 

#table1 th, td {
    width:auto;
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#table_2 {
    width:50%;
    float:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

---

For now, that's going to be how I have it—until I figure out a way to extend the list across the page via styling. If you take notice, the border that's placed on the bottom of the list (navbar) elements (li) fades out and does not span across the page, which is not what I want. From a design point of view, the page looks inconsistent and edgy as the footer itself spans across the page. So, if you feel like you have an idea as how to fix that, keep me posted.

As an aside, I'd like to thank Peter Szombati for his contribution.

While it didn't really help in the end, he ended up giving me some perspective which lead to what I have above. If you take notice, I did take his styling advice for the second table (width).

Thank-you folks,

Have a nice day.

- T.R.G.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this class:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
```

CSS changes:

```
#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 730px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  width: auto;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2B9EFF;
}
```

HTML changes:

```
<div id="header">
<!-- Start NavBar -->
    <div id="navbar" name="nav-top">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul> 
</div><div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried editing it according to your second post and updated my html after referencing your first post, but it still isn't centered. Was I supposed to give the tables the "clear" class? Also, why didn't it center?

Comment: Thank you for what did you wrote. I understand now.